# Как добавить доп. поле в редактировании раздела инфоблока -Активированные купоны?

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте!
Пользователи вводят купоны, телефон, фамилию и т.д. -эта информация находится в профилях пользователей.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно, чтобы в таблице-Активированные купоны отражались дополнительно поля из их профилей например, компания, город, должность, его мобильный телефон.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В тех поддержки мне ответили: К сожалению, в стандартном функционале нельзя поля из одного информационного блока вывести в списке элементов другого информационнного блока. Вам нужно либо продублировать в элементах информацию из этих блоков создав свойства и заполнив их вручную или написав код, который будет это делать, либо кастомизировать код продукта.

Что прописать в коде?

Comment: Как Вам и ответили написать код который будет брать иинформацию из профилей пользователей и писать в соответсвующие поля в инфоблоке. Все нужные функции вы можете найти в [документации по АПИ](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/)

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы в таблице "Активированные купоны" были отражены дополнительные поля из профиля пользователей, необходимо выполнить следующее:

1. Создать свойство пользователя для каждого поля, которое нужно отобразить в таблице.
2. Добавить соответствующие поля на страницу редактирования профиля пользователя, чтобы пользователи могли заполнить их.
3. В файле шаблона таблицы "Активированные купоны" нужно добавить вывод дополнительных полей пользователей, которые вы хотите отобразить.

Например, для вывода дополнительного поля "Компания" в таблице "Активированные купоны" можно использовать следующий код в файле шаблона:

```
<?
foreach ($arResult['ROWS'] as $key => $arRow)
{
    $userId = $arRow['user_id'];

    // Получаем массив значений дополнительных полей пользователя
    $arUserFields = CUser::GetList(($by="ID"), ($order="asc"), array("ID" => $userId), array("SELECT" => array("UF_COMPANY")));

    // Выводим значение поля "Компания"
    $arFields = $arUserFields->Fetch();
    echo $arFields['UF_COMPANY']; 
}
?>
```

Аналогичным образом можно вывести любое дополнительное поле пользователя в таблице "Активированные купоны". Обратите внимание, что для вывода дополнительных полей пользователя необходимо использовать соответствующий метод API Битрикса, в данном примере используется метод CUser::GetList().